# JSON not reading php mysql numrows count

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  data WHERE Email = '$email'");
$num = array();
//Caculate the number of rows that have macthing username
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$num[] = $numrows;

if ($num != 0){
    $data = array('success' => 'true', 'message' => 'Incorrect Email');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

The if statement isn't processed and no JSON data is echoed, rather the script  freeze.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM data WHERE Email = '$email'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$num = intval($row['num']);
if ($num != 0) {
    $data = array('success' => 'true', 'message' => 'Email found');
} else {
    $data = array('success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Incorrect Email');
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're using `$num[]`.

```
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  data WHERE Email = '$email'");
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows != 0){
        $data = array('success' => 'true', 'message' => 'Correct Email');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        $data = array('success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Incorrect Email');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

try using following Jquery:

```
$.post('your_file.php',{email: 'your_email'},function(data){
  alert(data.success + ' ' + data.message);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching a scalar value `$numrows` into an array `$num[]`, so you have got an error.
Try using `$numrows` directly in the if statement, like this:

```
if ($numrows != 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  data WHERE Email = '$email'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
$data = array('success' => 'true', 'message' => 'Email found');
}
else{
$data = array('success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Incorrect Email');
}
echo json_encode($data);
```